# jQuery animate callback + Backbone: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, callback, closures

I'm not a newbie to JavaScript, but often I find its flexible ways (like defining anonymous function as callbacks and their scope) quite confusing. One thing I'm still struggling with are closures and scopes.

Take this example (from a Backbone model):

```
'handleRemove': function() {
    var thisModel = this;
    this.view.$el.slideUp(400, function() { thisModel.view.remove(); });
},
```

After the model is removed/deleted, this will animate its view and finally remove it from the DOM. This works just fine - but initially I tried the following code:

```
'handleRemove': function() {
    var thisModel = this;
    this.view.$el.slideUp(400, thisModel.view.remove );
},
```

Which is basically the same, but without the `function() {}` wrapper for the remove() call.

Can someone explain why the latter code does not work? I get the following exception/backtrace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined backbone-min.js:1272
_.extend.remove backbone-min.js:1272
jQuery.speed.opt.complete jquery-1.8.3.js:9154
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-1.8.3.js:974
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-1.8.3.js:1084
tick jquery-1.8.3.js:8653
jQuery.fx.tick
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the context (`this`) of the callback function changes to the element being animated by jQuery.

```
var obj = { fn: function() {         // Used as below, the following will print:
                alert(this === obj); // false
                alert(this.tagName); // "DIV"
          }};
$('<div>').slideUp(400, obj.fn);
```

Furthermore, Backbone's view.remove function looks like this ([source code](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/0.9.10/backbone.js#L1269-L1275)):

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
},
```

Because `this` is not the Backbone view object any more, `$el` is not defined. Hence you get the "Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined" error.

Another way to avoid the error is to use Underscore's [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) method:

```
this.view.$el.slideUp(400, _.bind(thisModel.view.remove, this) );
```